# iOS 4.3 SDK does not show up in Xcode 3.2

Tags: xcode3.2

I am currently trying to learn iPhone development. The books out there right now are written for xCode 3.2.  I have downloaded and installed xCode 3.2 and the iOS 4.3 SDK from Apple's website.  Even though I ensured iOS 4.3 was checked during the install, when I launch xCode and do "New Project"; I only have options for Mac and nothing for iPhone templates. How do I get the iPhone templates to be an option?

Thank you!